# Consider this commutative square of homomorphisms of modules. Prove $\xi$ carries $\ker h$ into $\ker h'$ and ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, exact-sequence

[image]

We have by the diagram that $h\circ \eta = \xi\circ h'$. Also, $\ker h = \{x\in X| h(x) = 0_y\}$. What can I say about $\ker \eta$? It's $\{y\in Y | \eta(y) = 0\}$. I thought of saying that every element of $Y$ is in the form $h(x)$ for $x\in X$, but this isn't necessarily true since $h$ is not mentioned to be onto, right? So how can I relate $\ker h$ with $\eta$? How can I do the same for $\xi$ and $h'$?

Also, which property of $\xi$ and $\eta$ that are useful so we can say that they create those homomorphisms?

I think the exercise first asks me to show something that will help me find an exact sequence, and somehow it will help me to relate those things, but I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the composition backwards, we have:

$\eta \circ h = h' \circ \xi$

So suppose $x \in \text{ker }h$. This means $h(x) = 0_Y$, and since $\eta$ is a homomorphism, we have $\eta(0_Y) = 0_{Y'}$.

Since $\eta \circ h = h' \circ \xi$, we have $(h'\circ \xi)(x) = h'(\xi(x)) = 0_{Y'}$, so $\xi(x) \in \text{ker }h'$.

This shows $\xi|_{\text{ker }h}: \text{ker }h \to \text{ker }h'$.

Hopefully this gets you started on the other three properties.

We can regard the pair $(\xi,\eta)$ as a "$2$-morphism", that is a morphism between two morphisms (composition of $2$-morphisms being the obvious concatenation of commutative squares). The special property this pair has is that it forms a commutative square with $(h,h')$.

$2$-morphisms between exact sequences are used in many "diagram-chasing" style proofs.